# Search results for Kindle Unlimited?

Tags: search, amazon, kindle

On my Kindle device I can filter search results to "Kindle Unlimited" only.  I thought that I'd seen a similar option on the web interface through the Amazon website to search Kindle books, but see no such option.

How can I filter or sort to see Kindle Unlimited books on a specific [search](https://ebookfriendly.com/find-kindle-unlimited-ebooks/) as:

> 2. Browse and search entire Kindle Unlimited catalog A much better option is to go directly to the entire list of Kindle Unlimited
>      eligible books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "All Departments" to "Kindle Store" and make your search.

When the search results come up, in the left-side navbar check "Kindle Unlimited Eligible".